# Bluetooth Headset media buttons not working on Android using media2 nor media3

Tags: android, android-mediasession, mediabrowserservicecompat

I'm building an app which needs to trigger an audio menu. For that purpose I need to intercept clicks on media buttons, specifically the play/pause button.

It is working fine using wired headsets and using the media button present in the `Notification` for my foreground service.

But I do not receive media button events when I use a Bluetooth Headset.

I am missing something because the [UAMP](https://github.com/android/uamp) and [media3](https://github.com/androidx/media/tree/release/demos/session) samples work.

**Question is : what am I missing ?**

The samples are so complex I could not find out, I wish there was a sample code not using `ExoPlayer` but there is not.

**I made a sample project demonstrating the issue here : https://github.com/Ryfacto/MediaBluetoothHeadsetIssue.**

Thank you for your help, I'm really *desperate*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems related to an android bug when using `TTS` to play audio.

See this answer : [Catching android media button events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58471964/catching-android-media-button-events)

This issue is known by Google and referenced here : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/249741615

Answer (score 0):

If you use media3 it supports your requirements

reference

https://youtu.be/sTIBDcyCmCg?t=737

`you just need to extend MediaSessionService/medialibraryservice and override  onGetSession`

[Details of MediaSessionService/medialibraryservice](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media3/getting-started/playing-in-background#provide-access)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I just updated mine with the reference to the issue in Google Issue Tracker. It is a known issue...

Comment: Media library service is leaking everything, no way to release. No way to implment that.